# NoClassDefFoundError, Could not find class ***

Tags: android, api, noclassdeffounderror

I am working on an app which runs fine on my emulator (Android 4.0.3) and on my device running Android 4.1.2. I also had this app running fine on another device running Android 2.2.2, but it no longer runs on this older device. The error I get is NoClassDefFoundError when defining an intent in an onClick method in my MainMenuActivity.

Since testing the app on the older device I have made several changes, but the relevant one seems to be that I have updated the Android sdk to API 17 (from API 15, I believe).

I do have a jar file that I am including in the app, but it is not used in the class which the NoClassDefFoundError refers to.

I have tried many of the proposed solutions to these problems, such as defining a new folder called libs and putting the jar file in there, or going to the build path, selecting the file under Order and Export, then moving it up to the top and cleaning and rebuilding.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as this app has a minimum sdk version of 8.

Thank you very much!

**Edit**

I believe I have found the issue. I was implementing android.widget.PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener in the activity which causes the error, but eclipse was not giving me any warning that this is only valid for API 11 and higher. Not sure why this is. In any case, I will have to find some work around to get the effect I need. I'll mark this as solved, but any suggestions on how to do that would be appreciated.

Thanks again!

Comment: It would be great if you post the code snippet.

Comment: Whats your ADT version? Are you using any jars?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was implementing android.widget.PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener in the activity which causes the error, but eclipse was not giving me any warning that this is only valid for API 11 and higher. Removing this implementation and the associated methods did the trick.